# Android - get json with variables in path

Tags: android, json, url, getjson, path-variables

how can I set variables in url to get json in Android?
In most tutorials is method like this:

```
public String makeServiceCall(String reqUrl) {
    String response = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(reqUrl);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        // read the response
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
        response = convertStreamToString(in);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "MalformedURLException: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "ProtocolException: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "IOException: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return response;
}
```

Where *requURL* is String, for example: *http://192.168.1.3:5000/test*. And what if I want to set in this URL variable? For example, *[http://192.168.1.3:5000/test/{id}](http://192.168.1.3:5000/test/%7Bid%7D)*, where *id* is Integer. I dont want use parameters, I want use variables in path. It is possible?

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Using a library like retrofit 2 or volley and gson for serialization can simplify network calls for you, have you looked into such solutions?

Comment: No, I am totally beginer and I never heard about these libraries. Can you recommend tutorials for these libraries?

Comment: Here's some starting point for retrofit2
https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-getting-started-and-android-client
and the official https://square.github.io/retrofit/

I'm not sure how steep a climb it'll be, but there's plenty of help around if you need